# printing corresponding item in list to another list containing numbers

Tags: python, list

My problem is this. 
These are the two lists

```
codes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'l']
pas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

How would I find the position of all the 'a' in the codes list. And then print out the corresponding item in the pas list.
This is what the output should be. They should also be sorted with the .sort() function.

```
1
4
8
11
```

I have come up with this code. (That doesnt work)

```
qwer = [i for i,x in enumerate(codes) if x == common]
qwe = [qwer[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(qwer), 1)] 
print(pas[qwe])
```

What would be the best way to get the correct output?

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings or variables in your `codes` list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> pas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> codes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'l']
>>> result = sorted(i for i,j in zip(pas,codes) if j=='a')
>>> for i in result:
...     print i
... 
1
4
8
11
```

Comment: How would you make this code print each output on a new line?

Comment: Just iterate through the list while creating and print the item.

Comment: There is no need for the `[]` brackets, `sorted()` will create a list from the iterator. ;)

Comment: Oh, right you are. Actually, I formed a list first, then saw OP needs a sorted one, so wrapped it with `sorted` without thinking. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve it. Your example lists are:

```
>>> codes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'l']
>>> pas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

**Approach 1:** Using `enumerate`:

```
>>> indices = [pas[i] for i, x in enumerate(codes) if x == "a"]
indices = [1, 4, 8, 11]
```

**Approach 2**: Using `zip`:

```
>>> [p for p, c in zip(pas, codes) if c == 'a']
[1, 4, 8, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added another way to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
codes = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'l'])
pas = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])

index = np.where(codes=='a')
values = pas[index]

In [122]: print(values)
[ 1  4  8 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
codes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'i', 'j', 'a', 'l']
pas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

[pas[index] for index, element in enumerate(codes) if element == "a"]
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.